# Edge Extension: Need to share credentials with a WPF

Tags: javascript, wpf, file, local, microsoft-edge-extension

I have a WPF app that stores credentials in a local file. I need to be able to access this file from an Edge extension or to somehow communicate the credentials from the WPF to the Edge extension. Can an Edge extension use the File API or is there something similar to Native Messaging for WPF that would allow me to communicate with the Edge extension?

Answer (score 0):

As of builds 15002 and above (only available to Windows Insiders currently), Microsoft Edge supports native messaging to UWAs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/native-messaging

If you want to communicate with a WPFapp, you'll need to use the Desktop Bridge to convert it to a UWA before continuing.

If you need to sign up for the Windows Insider Program, you can do so here: https://insider.windows.com. Native messaging will also be available in the Windows 10 Creators Update once it's released publicly!